# s3 logs - What are these values?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, socket

I am trying to figure out why I am having a lot of socket timeout errors when running `serverless deploy -v` - https://github.com/serverless/serverless

I enabled logging on the S3 bucket that the error is happening on, the first CloudFormation file always seems to be uploaded fine, but the service .zip fails 80% of the time.

```
Serverless: Stack create finished...
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Uploading CloudFormation file to S3...
Serverless: Uploading service .zip file to S3 (3.75 MB)...


Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 Your socket connection to the server was not read from
 or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections
 will be closed.
```

A failed log looks like -

```
PUT /serverless/serverless-crud/dev/1488408196861-2017-03-01T22%3A43%3A16.861Z/serverless-crud.zip  HTTP/1.1    400 RequestTimeout  360 3929245 20033   -   -   aws-sdk-nodejs/2.7.13 linux/v7.5.0
```

A success looks like -

```
PUT /serverless/serverless-crud/dev/1488408364005-2017-03-01T22%3A46%3A04.005Z/serverless-crud.zip  HTTP/1.1    200 -   -   3929245 17199   79  -   aws-sdk-nodejs/2.7.13 linux/v7.5.0
```

Is there a place where I can find what these values relate to? Like the 360.

Also, any suggestions on how to fix/debug this timeout error?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html

Comment: Isn't serverless kind of an oxymoron in respect to asking a question on server Fault? You probably want the newly minted https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah, didn't really know where to ask. Thanks I'll check it out